# Hibernate tutorial example not work

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to follow this tutorial : http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/

and there one side has @OneToMany mapping and the other has @OneToOne. Is that possible ? I am getting error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.springapp.mvc.entities.EmployeeEntity.accounts in mappedBy of com.springapp.mvc.entities.AccountEntity.employee
```

Comment: error is the same, but the code is totally different. It's definitely not a duplicate question.

Comment: `@JOINCOLUMN(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")` where's `"EMPLOYEE_ID"` in there? Also is it many to one or one to many in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have that. If one side is One to Many, the other side has to be Many to one.